# Adding custom polyfills to the polyfill.ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

The project at work is not working correctly in Edge because of TextEncoder. That is its not defined in edge so the code breaks.

I've started looking into how I can add polyfills to my angular project, but I can't seem to find the right one on npm. That is I don't feel like  the ones I looked at would work.

I found the polyfill here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder#Polyfill

But when I add that code directly to the polyfill.ts it throws an error, saying it can't compile it.

What would be the correct way of going about this? How should I add that polyfill, or is there some npm package I didn't look at which is the solution?

Comment: please share your polyfill.ts and the error details

Comment: I can't edit the question to add all that, because I don't have that many points yet. But here is the error

Comment: ERROR in src/polyfills.ts(88,5): error TS2322: Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '{ new (): TextEncoder; prototype: TextEncoder; }'.
  Type '() => void' provides no match for the signature 'new (): TextEncoder'.
src/polyfills.ts(131,62): error TS2339: Property 'subarray' does not exist on type 'any[] | Uint8Array'.
  Property 'subarray' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
src/polyfills.ts(133,16): error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'length' because it is a read-only property.
src/polyfills.ts(142,59): error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'encoding' because it is a read-only property.

Comment: As I said, I just took that code and added it in the end of my polyfill.ts. I just wanted to test for starters just to see if its okay after, but couldn't really do that either

Comment: Did you try using import from npm - https://github.com/anonyco/FastestSmallestTextEncoderDecoder

Comment: Hope this is the npm package you are looking for - https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder

Comment: I didn't come across this one, but I'll try it. Is it enough for me to import that in the polyfill.ts file?

Comment: yes import it in polyfill.ts and it should work for you and let me know, if you find any issues , I will try to replicate it in stackbliz in case of any error/issue

Comment: How exactly should I import it? Because I'm not getting an auto suggestion in IntellIJ and "import 'fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder';" is not really working :(

Comment: I tried some other libraries too, and adding them as an import. But still the same. In Edge the TextEncoder is undefined and the code dies. The angular project starts, but the request fails because the encoder is not defined...

Comment: Actually it seems its something unrelated. I added the polyfill directly in the index.html and it does execute it. But the error still occurs. So I'll add the error here or make a new question for that Stompjs part. Because it dies inside that.

Comment: https://github.com/stomp-js/ng2-stompjs/issues/137

Comment: Hmmmm.....that fixes the error but stompjs can't connect still. Its trying to reconnect nonstop